# R: Extracting the index of the final / last minimum value in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector

`y <- c(10:1, c(0.1,0.1,0.1))`

if I do `which.min(y)`, it returns the index `11`. 
However, I want it to return the last / final index, where the minimum has been seen. 
I have a clumsy of doing this, which is:

`rev(which(y == min(y)))[1]`

But is there a better way to do this  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? On the same concept with what you have, you could, also, use `length(y) - which.min(rev(y)) + 1`

Comment: i mean like a more elegant way, a 1-line code that can do something like `which.min(y, last.index = T)`

Answer (score 2):

I would just create my own utility function

```
which.min2 <- function(x, last.index = FALSE, ...){
  if(last.index) max(which(x == min(x, ...))) else which.min(x)
}

which.min2(y, TRUE)
## [1] 13
which.min2(y)
## [1] 11
```

This will also work if you have `NA`s in your vector

```
y <- c(10:1, c(0.1,0.1,NA))

which.min2(y, TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 12
which.min2(y, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max.col`  function, which has a richer way of handling ties, but it requires a matrix and I did not find the corresponding min function:

```
> y <- c(10:1, c(0.1,0.1,0.1))
> max.col(t(as.matrix(-y)), ties.method='last')
[1] 13
>
```

So depending on how your real `y` vector is built, you cain gain from this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail(order(y, decreasing=T),1)
#[1] 13
```